# How can I make Perl 6 be round-trip safe for Unicode data?

Tags: unicode, raku

A naïve Perl 6 program is not round-trip safe with respect to Unicode.  It appears as if it internally uses *Normalization Form Composition* (NFC) for the Str type:

```
$ perl -CO -E 'say "e\x{301}"' | perl6 -ne '.say' | perl -CI -ne 'printf "U+%04x\n", ord for split //'
U+00e9
U+000a
```

Poking through the docs I can't see anything about this behavior and I find it very shocking. I can't believe you have to drop back to the byte level to round-trip text:

```
$ perl -CO -E 'say "e\x{301}"' | perl6 -e 'while (my $byte = $*IN.read(1)) { $*OUT.write($byte) }' | perl -CI -ne 'printf "U+%04x\n", ord for split //'
U+0065
U+0301
U+000a
```

Do all text files have to be in NFC to be safely round-tripped with Perl 6?  What if the document is supposed to be in NFD?  I must be missing something here. I cannot believe this is intentional behavior.

Comment: I think it's intended. All the string in `perl6` is processed to NFC form, then store internally  in NFG form, which is the `perl6` way to deal with un-precomposed graphemes properly. Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311280/38906. At least the `Str.ords` mentioned this https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_ords

Comment: That seems insanity to me.  I was willing to deal with all the changes to syntax, but not being able to round trip a text file when your raison d'être is string handling (especially Unicode string handling) is ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

The answer seems to be to use the Uni type (the base class for NFD, NFC, etc), but it doesn't really do that now and there is no good way to get the file into a Uni string.  So, until some unnamed point in the future, you cannot roundtrip a non-normalized file unless you treat it as bytes.

Comment: @zostay A way that does not entail reading blocks in as a Buf and then using a UTF-8 parser you have to write yourself (the built-in one applies NFC) to convert to Uni.  A good way would be something like `$*IN.lines(:Uni)`.

Comment: The problem is that nothing but Str and Str-related goodies understand "lines" at this point. The closest I can think of is something like `$*IN.Supply(:bin).map({ Uni.new(.list) })` and then you have to break the lines up, which becomes the ugly part.

Comment: @zostay What part of that is decoding the UTF-8? My reading of that is that you are stuffing bytes in the Uni.

Comment: @zostay Yeah, I worked through what all of that does and (unless I am gravely mistaken) it boils down to `Uni.new(Buf[uint8].new(101,204,129).list)` which yields `Uni:0x<0065 00cc 0081>`  not the "desired" `Uni:0x<0065 0301>`.

Comment: Ah! Of course... now I got it. I also found a better partial answer, but still unhelpful. Try out `perl6 -ne '.NFD.say'`. I think that may get you the Uni you want, but it still won't really help you since Uni doesn't really do anything useful and, unfortunately, Uni.gist is more like Str.perl than Str.gist, so you can't just .say to get the bytes back as you might expect to be able to do and .NFD.Str.say engages NFG again, so no help there. I may try a PR to address this though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126049/discussion-between-zostay-and-chas-owens).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`UTF8-C8`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/unicode#File_Handles_and_I/O). From the [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/unicode#File_Handles_and_I/O):

> You can use UTF8-C8 with any file handle to read the exact bytes as
>   they are on disk. They may look funny when printed out, if you print
>   it out using a UTF8 handle. If you print it out to a handle where the
>   output is UTF8-C8, then it will render as you would normally expect,
>   and be a byte for byte exact copy.

Comment: UTF8-C8 isn't really a good solution (but is probably the only solution currently). The codepoints for e and combining acute are stored as "e\x[10FFFD]xCCx\x[10FFFD]x81" (ie it stores the combining acute its UTF-8 representation in hex with each byte preceded by U+10FFFD and an x). You also have to explicitly print the string out using UTF8-C8 or the nasty mess will be written rather than the combining acute.  Note that not all combining acutes will be affected, only ones that are attached to a character that has a NFC form (eg x combining acute is stored in a sane manner).